# IE image not getting loaded with X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff

Tags: spring, internet-explorer

**Intro**

I have spring MVC application I'm loading image from controller. For security purpose, I added `X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff` to my Spring application

By setting the following in springConfig xml `<security:content-type-options/>`

**Problem** : after this IE is not loading the images responded by controller. I suspect the content type is not set in the response. Because another site which is responding `X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff`  and `Content-Type:image/png;` is working fine.

**TRY1**
I tried to change my controller to set content type. But it is not happening.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserImage" , produces = org.springframework.http.MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody
void getUserImage(
        @RequestParam(value = "userId", required = false) int userId,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {
        //Get file and add it to response
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
        response.setContentType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type","image/png");
        response.flushBuffer();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
}
```

**TRY2**
I tried to add response header as the same way in method interceptor but still no luck.

But the same thing working in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/image/{personId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public HttpEntity<byte[]> getPhoto(@PathVariable int personId) {
        Person person = this.personService.getPersonById(personId);
        if (person != null && person.getProfileThumbnail() != null) {
            try {
                byte[] image;
                try {
                    image = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(msg + "/" + person.getUsername() + "/" + personId + ".png"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    image = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(defaultProfilePath));
                }
                HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
                headers.setContentLength(image.length);
                return new HttpEntity<>(image, headers);
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

        } 
}
```

What I am basically doing is checking if there is an image on File-system for the user, if not then I am loading a default image. Right now it works on all browser, so even if personid is 0, I get default image back, with the else cause, which I have not posted here.

Comment: Content-type is set but IE still not loading the image. Who built this IE? Most frustrated Web browser in the world.

Comment: You are returning void, how do you expect it would work? Or is this your attempt at trolling?

Comment: No Borg, Let me clear. it is working in Chrome and FF. Without content-type. And your code I tried to add, and your code is setting the content-type but still the IE is not loading the image, but Chrome and FF is loading.

Comment: Change your return-type.

Comment: Sir I changed as you mentioned. I said, I tried your code. And it is working great i.e setting the content type, but IE is not loading the image. How can I use your code without changing the return type. It will throw compilation error.